# How to store text from a webpage using Ruby?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation, ruby

Ruby / automation beginner here - I'm trying to get and store an email address from a webpage using the element id, but am getting the error `undefined local variable or method 'customer_email_address' for main:Object (NameError)` when executing it.

The aim is to store the email address, and then login to our back office to search for it - so I *think* I'm looking for a storeValue or getValue equivalent?

This is the page:

[image: @driver.find_element(:id, "customer_email_address")]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = driver.find_element(id: 'customer_email_address')
a.text
```

replace double quotes with single quotes and there is not getText in ruby but text

read this :

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/web_element/

**//working syntax**

```
 require 'selenium-webdriver'
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
begin
  # Navigate to URL
  driver.get 'https://google.com'

  # Get search box element from webElement 'q' using Find Element
  search_bar = driver.find_element(id: 'customer_email_address').text

  # Perform action using WebElement
  search_bar.send_keys 'Webdriver'
ensure
  driver.quit
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was getting the same results with both single and double quotes, but have switched them to single as it looks like it's best practice? I've also edited the question - I'm trying to get (like copy or store) the email address and not just find the element. My apologies, I should have made it clearer.

Comment: Did you try the working syntax? to get Text , you should use element.text . In ruby get text is a property and not a method

Comment: try this syntax `driver.find_element(id: 'customer_email_address').text`

Comment: Yup, that works great - but does `driver.find_element(id: 'customer_email_address').text` not just find the element?

Comment: @trashpanda driver.findelemrnt(bla) returns a element and then we are calling .text from that element , you can separate it . Like a = driver.findelment(bla)

Comment: And then a.text

Comment: Hey @PDHide, thanks for your help yesterday - I've gone with a different solution which avoids having to find and store the value. Instead, I'm defining it at the start of the script with `email_address = "trash.panda+#{Time.now.to_i}@searchingyourbins.com"`, and then calling it when needed with `.send_keys(email_address)` and `#{email_address}` :) Happy to accept your answer though as I'm sure it'll be correct for someone who's better with Ruby!